# Sending firebase invites on iOS logging in firebase auth using Facebook token only

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-invites

Is it possible to send Firebase Invites on iOS, Logging in Firebase Auth using a Facebook token as a login provider?
On Firebase SDK, documentation is ambiguous wether I need to use a real google account or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. Although documentation is not clear on this.
In order to send Firebase Invites on iOS, you must be logged either in Google Sign In or in Firebase Auth, but with a Google Account (although Firebase Auth allows many other means of authentication).
This makes Firebase invites on iOS not really useful, since most iOS users do not even have a google account.